# How to remove duplicate rows by substituting the zero value with another number in pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, data-science

So, I have this column
[image]

And, I wanted to convert into this column
[image]

I want to replace zero with number. So, how can I do that using pandas python?

Answer (score 3):

Try with `groupby`

```
out = df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3'],as_index=False).max()
```

Comment: I mean, I wasn't sure if they wanted `max` but I'm glad that was it (-:

Comment: But what if it has a negative number, let's say we have a negative number and I want to replace 0 with negative, will that work?

Comment: I have a bunch of column like col1, col2, col3. I have around 12 column in group by. When I ran in Juypter notebook, it returned a MemoryError: Unable yo allocate 272. TiB for an array with space(.....) and data type int16. 

Is there a other way to solve this issue?